# Remove an object from ObservableCollection by clicking an item in GridView C#

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, observablecollection

I have an observable collection:

`private ObservableCollection<Icon> MyContactInst;`

The collection holds some objects which are changed in real time by Add Button and Remove Button.

I view the objects in a GridView:

```
<GridView Name="GridView2" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyContactInst}"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
              ItemClick="GridView2_ItemClick">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Icon">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image Width="65" Source="{x:Bind IconImagePath}"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind FullName}"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind Age}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

I want to click on one of the objects in the GridView and then clicking the Remove Button to erase it from the collection and the GridView. Is there any efficient way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things needed to achieve what you want:

1) Add a public property of type `bool` to class `Icon`. Class `Icon` also needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. You can find a tutorial how to do that here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.95).aspx

The code you'll need to add looks like this:

```
private bool isSelected; 


public bool IsSelected
{
   get 
   {
      return isSelected;
   }
   set 
   {
      isSelected = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
   }    
}
```

2) Bind to that value via `XAML`:

```
<GridView.RowStyle>                 
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewRow}">                              
           <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>                 
     </Style>             
</GridView.RowStyle>
```

What we achieved so far is that every `Icon` in the `GridView` (which repesents all `Icons` in your `Observable Collection`) will have its `IsSelected` Property set to true if you select it in your `GridView`.

3) Now removing `Icons` from your `Observable Collection` can just be done via

```
public void RemoveIcon()
{
    foreach (int i = MyContactInst.Count-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        if (icon.IsSelected == true)
        {
            MyContactInst.Remove(icon);
        }
    }
 }
```

You can trigger this function via `events` or via `Command` binding to a button.